# How can a Delphi application detect the network proxy settings of a Windows PC?

Tags: delphi, proxy, delphi-7

I have a Delphi application that communicates with web servers on the Internet using the [Indy components](http://www.indyproject.org/). Most users of the application have direct Internet connections but some are behind a proxy server of a local network.  I don't want to have to ask the users to lookup their proxy server in the [Internet Options / Connections / LAN Settings dialog](http://toybase.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/ie-proxy-settings.png)

[alt text http://toybase.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/ie-proxy-settings.png](http://toybase.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/ie-proxy-settings.png)

as quite frankly most people won't know or care what this setting is.

Can I get this information via some system calls from a Delphi-7 appplication?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Via WinAPI -- [WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384096(VS.85).aspx). You gotta love MS's long WINAPI names ^_^.

After OP edit: You can read from the registry, AFAIR it would be located here :

```
 [ HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Internet Settings ]
```

Comment: +1 but if I'm not mistaken, that's for IE only, though. Firefox and the other browsers maintain their own Proxy settings.

Comment: That's true but I assumed that if the OP want's to get it via system calls, then that's what he's after.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know what to search for, I found some code here: http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Delphi/borland.public.delphi.nativeapi/2004-01/0205.html

Answer (score 4):

The Delphi code for [Kornel Kisielewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233522/)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013802/how-can-a-delphi-application-detect-the-network-proxy-settings-of-a-windows-pc/2013836#2013836):

```
uses Registry, Windows;

function detectIEProxyServer() : string;
begin
  with TRegistry.Create do
    try
        RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
        if OpenKey('\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings', False) then begin
          Result := ReadString('ProxyServer');
          CloseKey;
        end
        else
          Result := '';
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: NB: TRegistry.ReadString():  "If the Registry entry contains something other than a string, an exception is raised."

Answer (score 3):

Here's another method that I use, which doesn't require direct registry access.  This works under D2007, but I can't see why it wouldn't work under D7.

```
uses
  WinInet,
  SysUtils;

function UseIEProxyInfo(var ProxyHost: String; var ProxyPort: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ProxyInfo: PInternetProxyInfo;
  Len: LongWord;
  ProxyDetails: String;
  s2: String;
  i1: Integer;

  procedure RemoveProtocol(var str: string);
  var
    i1 : integer;
  begin
    i1 := PosText('://', str);
    if i1 > 0 then
      Delete(str, 1, i1 + 2);
    i1 := PosText('http=', str);
    if i1 > 0 then begin
      Delete(str, 1, i1 + 4);
      str := SubStr(str, 1, ' ');
    end;
  end;

begin
  Result := False;

  Len := 4096;
  GetMem(ProxyInfo, Len);
  try
    if InternetQueryOption(nil, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, ProxyInfo, Len) then
    begin
      if ProxyInfo^.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY then
      begin
        Result := True;
        ProxyDetails := ProxyInfo^.lpszProxy;

        RemoveProtocol(ProxyDetails);
        s2 := SubStr(ProxyDetails, 2, ':');
        if s2 <> '' then
        begin
          try
            i1 := StrToInt(s2);
          except
            i1 := -1;
          end;

          if i1 <> -1 then
          begin
            ProxyHost := SubStr(ProxyDetails, 1, ':');
            ProxyPort := i1;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(ProxyInfo);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It would be good to know the definition of your SubStr function, as it is not entirely obvious here.

Comment: @mj2008: it's a reference to a function in the madStrings.pas unit from the madExcept exception handling library. You can find some online help here: http://help.madshi.net/StringSub.htm

Answer (score 1):

You would have to get the proxy setting from the browser, which could be in several different locations depending on the browser in use.

You might consider looking into [Web Proxy Autodiscovery Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol), which automatically detects proxy settings on a network.

Comment: The users will most definitely be using IE :) but thanks for the link!